# Delay in light turning on when switch flipped

Tags: electrical

What causes a delay in a light when I flip the switch? It is a led bulb and it is the second one in a circuit of four. I changed the light and it still does it. I also checked all the wiring to see if it was tight and had a good ground. Whats next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes LED lights are controlled by transformers or relays. It may be that when the switch is flipped on the current will have to flow to a transformer that changes the household voltage to DC voltage.

Comment: all the lights are the same why would it only affect one?

Comment: If you got a LED lamp from a different run of lamps, it could be off just a little. It is annoying but it should be okay. Just save the receipts if you have to exchange it or if the lamp does not make its full life.

Comment: I changed it once so it sounds like I might just have to live with it.

Comment: @Ron-do the LED bulbs install into a LED fixture? or do they have all the required circuit devices (drivers) built into the bulb? I ask because it may have something to do with the circuitry controlling that second LED. You know it probably not the bulb since it's been replaced (to be sure swap out the bulb with one of the 3 others in that circuit). The delay is localized to that second LED fixture. If there are no other power sources or controllers the intermittent issue must be from the second fixture. If you can remove it and test it out of circuit that would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Ron- Describing the bulb and fixture would help. Power rating, type of led, brand name.

Comment: They are LED lights fixtures that are all in one to resemble a can light bought them at Menards. Would have to take whole light down to swap it with another one in circuit but it would narrow it down to do that.

Comment: they are Sylvania brand 13w ultra LED

Comment: Ok. they are similar to  recessed light fixtures.  Try swapping bulbs from any of the other 3 known working LED's or install the bulb from the intermittent (2nd) fixture in any of the other 3 and see if the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: The instructions call them light disks so I think you might have to change the whole light not just the bulb,just installed these as porch lights on a porch overhang